# Error when trying to add / remove Authorized JavaScript origins for Google OAuth Client ID

Tags: google-api

This question is for anyone at Google who might monitor this feed - y'all [note](https://support.google.com/googleapi/answer/7014572?hl=en&ref_topic=7014869) that users should ask for support here, since there doesn't seem to be another accessible support channel for the Google API Console.

In the Google APIs Console, when trying to add or remove Authorized JavaScript origins tied to a Client ID for a Web Application, I encounter this error after clicking "Save":

[image]

That popup includes a link to "Submit Feedback", which I've done twice without any response from the Google team.

I am an Owner on the project, and have been able to successfully add / remove origins in the past (this issue started last week). Another person on my team - also a project Owner - has been unable to add new origins, as well.

I've tried:

- Clearing all Google cookies, and browser cache.
- Signing out of the API Console, and signing back in.
- Doing this in another browser (Firefox), which also fails to work.
- Removing the other person on my team as an Owner, and re-adding his permissions.

I am not logged into any other Google account in this profile of Chrome, or in Firefox.

If anyone has suggestions for how to resolve this, I'd love the help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is resolved. Since my app interacts with the Gmail API, given the recent issues on Gmail phishing and [Google's improved vetting process](https://gsuiteupdates.googleblog.com/2017/05/updating-developer-identity-guidelines.html), it turns out you can no longer submit changes to Credentials through the Google API Console for apps that request. Google notes on that blog post:

> You may see an error message as you’re registering new applications or
>   modifying existing application attributes in the Google API Console,
>   Firebase Console, or Apps Script editor as a result of this change.

The Google team directed me to [this form](https://support.google.com/code/contact/oauth_app_update) to submit updates to the OAuth Consent Screen or the Credentials (e.g. changing Authorized Javascript origins).

I hope others who face this issue are able to find this post helpful!